# Is strip casting the same thing as continuous casting?

Tags: steel, metallurgy, casting

Web searches are surprisingly ambivalent on this question. In steel production, do strip casting and continuous casting refer to the same process?

Comment: This is ambivslent? Seems clear enough: http://www.jfe-21st-cf.or.jp/chapter_6/6h_1.html

Comment: strip seems to be a type of continuous casting

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same. The  product shape is the major difference. Traditional continuous casting billets are round or square. Several years ,in the mid 90's, there was no commercial "strip" casting ( steel).  Although the early developments of continuous costing produced strip form of low melting metals like zinc.

Comment: This answer is for general public. For mill metallurgists ,there is a dramatic difference between regular and strip casting.